# Strange behavior while splitting string with non-word character regex

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

**Case 1(Trailing space)**

```
> "on behalf of all of us  ".split(/\W+/)
 => ["on", "behalf", "of", "all", "of", "us"]
```

but if there is leading space then it gives following

**Case 2(Leading space)**

```
> "  on behalf of all of us".split(/\W+/)
 => ["", "on", "behalf", "of", "all", "of", "us"]
```

I was expecting result of Case 1 for Case 2 also.

**ADDED**

```
> "@dhh congratulations!!".split(/\W+/)
 => ["", "dhh", "congratulations"]
```

Would anyone please help me to understand the behavior?

Comment: well i think that trailing white-space isn't considered as a value and in leading white-space you have characters after it so hence considering white-space as value. In Case 1 add one more character after trailing white-space! and check whether it appears in array or not?

Comment: Even if you add any number of spaces at the end result is consistent.

Comment: i said to add character like "." after trailing space and see whether dot includes in the array or not .. .  .

Comment: well, i think someone got solution for you below :)

Comment: Work around is first replace all non-word characters with empty string appearing in the start of the string and then split. "    `@dhh congratulations!!".gsub(/^\W+/,'').split /\W+/` However I am still looking for answer to the puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Update]**

Skip regex, just Split on space!

```
> "@dhh congratulations!!".split
 => ["@dhh", "congratulations"]
```

---

`\W` matches **any** non-word character including space. so as the parser sees a space in start & some chars AFTER the space; it splits. But if the space it at the end, there is no other wordy char`[a-zA-Z0-9]` present to split with.

To get consistent behavior, you should remove whitespaces using `#strip` method.

**Case 1(Trailing space)**

```
1.9.3p327 :007 > " on behalf of all of us ".strip.split(/\W+/) 
 => ["on", "behalf", "of", "all", "of", "us"]
```

**Case 2(Leading space)**

```
1.9.3p327 :008 > "on behalf of all of us ".strip.split(/\W+/) 
 => ["on", "behalf", "of", "all", "of", "us"]
```

Comment: It is very likely that first character is non-word character most of the time in my case. Would you please suggest alternate for this?

Comment: you can split on space then? added an example

Comment: @AmitPatel, If the first character is "garbage", you have to prepare/clean the string prior to splitting. That's just a normal part of normalizing the input to get a consistent behavior. Often we do a strip to remove leading/trailing whitespace, and is something done in every language I've ever worked with.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks. I verified with javascript as well and getting same result.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split):

> **split(pattern=$;, [limit]) → anArray**
>
> [...]
>   If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed. If limit is a positive number, at most that number of fields will be returned (if limit is 1, the entire string is returned as the only entry in an array). If negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

Just for documentation, following works for me

```
 " @dhh congratulations!!".gsub(/^\W+/,'').split /\W+/
```

Another one

```
 " @dhh congratulations!!".scan /\w+/
```

Both gives expected results. However there is a caveat for short forms like

```
 > " Don't be shy.".scan /\w+/
 => ["Don", "t", "be", "shy"]
```

I am actually collecting words which are not articles, conjunctions, prepositions etc. So anyway I am ignoring such short forms and hence I used this solution.

I am preparing words cloud from tweets. If you know any proven algorithm please share.